# htaccess RewriteRule leaving the current directory scope

Tags: .htaccess, subdirectory, directory-structure

I'm creating a website based on wordpress on a hosting system (unfortunately not a dedicated system in this situation) and I am very limited in my configuration opportunities for Apache2.4.x / PHP8.

I was unable to convince my client to move to a more advanced environment, so I have to work with the given playground, as follows:

There is a website in /www/ which is linked to the domain (A-Record). There's an old man that maintains the current website until the new website is finished.

I am really not afraid that the old dev accesseses my development scope intentionally or uses PHP to do so to cause harm (he doesn't know PHP, he uploads locally generated HTML). He's an old man and I'm rather afraid that he accidently deletes, overwrites or moves my work while I'm working on the new website and I have to put it back together. He might be like "oh I don't know that folder" and it's gone.

My first task was to make and install certificates and enforce HTTPS, that worked pretty well so far.

Now I need [www.domain.tld/dev/](http://www.domain.tld/dev/) to show the wordpress site, however the old developer can access the www scope and I really don't want him to mess with my code. He barely knows HTML.

In opposite to him, I have full access and can go outside of the /www/ directory, so I created a /wordpress/. Unfortunately I have no option to add a subdomain for that on said host, either.

Now here's where my problem and my approaches kick in, I am unable to move /www/dev/ to show the /wordpress/ content which is not inside of /www/.

Theoretically I would do this on my root server but my client wants the website development to happen in his webspace. That's a bit strange but no subject to change. Just take that as given fact please.

So my htaccess rules for this are not doing anything and I can not spot what's wrong.
(Note: The .htaccess is laying inside of /www/)

```
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.tld [NC] 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.tld%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    #RewriteBase /
    #RewriteRule ^/dev /is/htdocs/wpCUSTOMERIDSTRIPPED/wordpress [QSA]
    #RewriteRule ^/dev/(.*)  /is/htdocs/wpCUSTOMERIDSTRIPPED/wordpress/$1 [QSA]

    RewriteBase /is/htdocs/wpCUSTOMERIDSTRIPPED
    RewriteRule ^/www/dev /wordpress [QSA]
    RewriteRule ^/www/dev/(.*)  /wordpress/$1 [QSA]
```

Thank you alot in advance.

Note: The search function did not help me further as I am moving outside of the scope of the active directory.

Comment: This probably belongs in ServerFault.

Comment: When you configure rewriting in .htaccess, the path RewriteRule matches against never starts with a `/`, that has been stripped off at this point already. So `^/dev` or `^/www/dev` will never match anything, the leading slash after the start-of-subject anchor `^` would need to be removed.